# App Engine Expando model get_by_id not working

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

python 2.7
app engine 1.8.5.1039

for the life of me I can't figure out whey My InventoryItem Expando model is returning None. My id is valid. I've checked the datastore more times than I'd like to remember. Do I have to pass the Expando model a parent to work properly?

```
class InventoryItem(db.Expando):
    def toDict(self):
        d = db.to_dict(self)
        d['id'] = self.key().id()
        return d

inventoryItem = InventoryItem(parent=toon.getInventory())
for k,v in item.iteritems():
    setattr(inventoryItem,k,v)
    inventoryItem.put()

inventoryItem_id = self.request.get("id")
        logging.info(inventoryItem_id)#5770237022568448
        item = InventoryItem.get_by_id(long(inventoryItem_id))#returns None
```

Comment: inventoryItem = InventoryItem(parent=toon.getInventory())
Is this the only place where you create the object? Are you doing put and get in a same transaction? get_by_id should work regardless it is exapando or not. Can you provide the screenshot of the datastore item you reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to get_by_id will need a parent to be supplied, because you are supplying a parent when you create the entity.  `InventoryItem(parent=toon.getInventory())`

See the call docs for `get_by_id(id, parent=None, app=None, namespace=None, **ctx_options)`

I would also suggest you go and read the docs on how key's work as a good understanding on what the use of parent means is pretty fundamental to using appengine.